# Css/Bootstrap : How can i align all list items in mobile mode when in large screen they got pull right and left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

let say in my large screen my list items got pull right or pull left coded like this :

```
<header id="main-header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                logo
            </a>

        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#main-navigation-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recommendation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Best Seller</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>


    </nav>

</header>
```

css :

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1400px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0;
}

/*=======================
       H E A D E R
========================*/

#main-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

/* main navbar */
.navbar.navbar-default {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin : 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-header {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}



 /*=======================
 M E D I A  Q U E R I E S
 ========================*/


@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 250px;
}

}
```

All is working well in large screens like desktop. but when i switch to mobile screens (767px) when i click the bars button the list are going everywhere [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEYTc.png). how can i solve this problem ? thanks.

Comment: You should post your CSS code.

Comment: Hi James will you also post your css please.

Comment: edit my question guys thank you

Comment: Have you tried overwriting `pull-right` in css media queries?

Comment: float : none; still no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `navbar-right` instead of `pull-right`.

**Working example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <style type="text/css">
      
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
      
<body>

<header id="main-header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                logo
            </a>

        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#main-navigation-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recommendation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Best Seller</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>


    </nav>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the pull-right class and just use a media query to float the list right on mobile only

So:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recommendation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Best Seller</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav rightNav">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

with

```
.rightNav {float: right}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
 float: none;
}
```